# Call API in particular windows credentials

Tags: c++

I want to call an API in particular Windows credentials,

One way is, write particular piece of code or API in another EXE and then execute the EXE in particular windows credentials. Please let me know if you are aware of any other solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`LogonUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28VS.85%29.aspx), then [`ImpersonateLoggenOnUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378612%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), then call your code, then call [`RevertToSelf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379317%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get back to the original credentials. You can do that either in your thread, or [create a separate thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and do it there. The latter is preferred so that you have the thread exited after that and not skip the `RevertToSelf()` call.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to understand what you're asking for, because I'm not sure what you mean by 'Windows credentials,' but you may want to look up 'impersonation.'

The MSDN page is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx; you can see the different types of impersonation and pick what fits your situation best.

In this case, it sounds like you want the `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` function.

Comment: The particular API operates/works depending upon the credentials under it is running. In my case my process or EXE is running under "USER A" but I want my API to run under "USER B".

Comment: @Rahul: that's indeed impersonation. +1 to dauphic for correctly guessing what you wanted.

Comment: +1 for dauphic but sharptooth was right on target. Thanks again guys.